# find the volume below the cone $z=2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and inside the cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I know I need to transform it into cylindrical system to integrate it but I don't know how to deal with r, since the cylinder is not center at (0,0)

Comment: Don't you have a third condition: "above the xy plane"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the volume is bounded below by the $xy$ plane, you need to ask yourself what is the projection of the volume in the $xy$ plane. And indeed, cylindrical coordinates are the way to go.

So obviously, the projection is the disc $(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1$, which you need to convert to polar coordinates. Expand, and you get
$$
x^2-2x+1 +y^2 \le 1\quad \Rightarrow \quad r^2\le 2 r \cos \theta \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le r\le 2  \cos \theta
$$
And careful with $\theta$, the cylinder is shifted along the $x$ axis, so 
$$
-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2
$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you very much! but why shifting will change the range of $\theta$? I cannot get through this part because the base of cylinder is still a whole circle

Comment: When you shift it on the $x$ axis, you place the circle in the plane $x\ge 0$. Or in other words, on the right of the $y$-axis. But the $y$ axes have equations $\theta=-\pi/2$ (the bottom one) and $\theta=\pi/2$ (the top one). So being on the right of $\theta=-\pi/2$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ means $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (2-\sqrt[n]{x^2+y^2}) dx dy$$ and put

$$x=1+r\cos{\theta}$$ and $$y=r\sin{\theta}$$ and $$dxdy=rdrd{\theta}$$

answer:$2\pi$